# R: multiple merge with big data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two big dataframes: DBa and DBb. All colums of DBb are in DBa.

I want to merge these two dataframes by all DBb's colums.

I'm trying:

```
new <- merge(DBa, DBb, by=colnames(DBb))
```

but it gives me the error:

```
Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y
```

How can I do it?

Comment: again: Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y

Comment: Though names match, do data types match? Be careful of `factors`. Post `str(DBa)` and `str(DBb)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are looking to merge the data frames, you should put them on top of each other with `rbind`. With merge you will put two data frames next to eachother, and you only need one common column (the key) which should be unique otherwise the results will be a mess. 
So use row bind (rbind). The columns must be in the same order and one data frame must not have more columns than the other.

```
new_data <- rbind(data1, data2)
```